# Bytecode verification issue tool

Tags: jvm, bytecode, websphere-8

We are facing a VerifyError in our application while deploying to WAS environment. The following is the exception:

```
Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:  Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError:  JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/org/jaxb/Input_JAXB_Deserialization_Stub, method=write(ILjava/lang/Object;)V, pc=356
```

We are still trying to identify the issue, but all efforts not going well. Is there any way that the libraries used in run time is good in bytecode compatibility?. For example, we can add all the libraries and run the byte code verification.

Comment: Do you have the actual classfile in question? Just look at the bytecode position in the error message. A stack mismatch should be pretty obvious.

Comment: This looks like a generated class. If a generated class is invalid, it’s indicating a bug in the generator. Filing a bug report would be the best action then. Stackoverflow can’t provide a remote diagnostic, especially not when all we got is that single exception message…